# Stop CALayer shadow from affecting subviews?

Tags: ios, uiview, ios8, calayer, shadow

I have a custom `UIControl`, and I want it to have a shadow, so I set the relevant properties on its `layer`.  A shadow appears around the view as desired, but a shadow also appears under the text of a `UILabel`, which is a subview. How do you stop this? I only want the shadow around the outer superview.

[image]

```
...
init() {        
    label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(label)

    self.layer.masksToBounds = false
    self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 2.0

    // Adding these lines trying to explicitly stop shadow on label...
    label.layer.shadowOpacity = 0
    label.layer.shadowColor = nil
    ...
}
```

Comment: Did you try to set zero shadow for label.layer after configuring self.layer shadow?

Comment: Yes I did. I added a couple lines to code in question.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

This happens when parent view has alpha less than 1.0 or has no background color (i.e is set to clear color). In that case shadow translates to subviews. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31313216/3329130) for more details.

Apple [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/LayerStyleProperties/LayerStyleProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH10-SW18) prove this:

> Figure A-7 shows several different versions of the same sample layer
>   with a red shadow applied. The left and middle versions include a
>   background color so the shadow appears only around the border of the
>   layer. However, the version on the right does not include a background
>   color. In this case, the shadow is applied to the layer’s content,
>   border, and sublayers.

[image: Shadow]

Comment: Yup, that outer view had alpha < 1.0.

Comment: what is the solution to prevent this happening?

Comment: @KvnH it depends. If you don't need a (semi)transparent superlayer just correct it's alpha to 1. In case you actually do need a (semi)transparent layer "behind" your views/layers just create another parent layer/view and add your transparent subview/sublayer to it as well as all other views. It should work.

Comment: Thanks ! you saved me a lot of time. I was clueless

Comment: Thank you. wasted more than 5 hours of time banging my head.

Answer (score 2):

its easy just change your subviews parent.

in other words make new parent above the your transparent shadow View and insert the subViews to this new parent view.