# Objectivec set shadow to parent view

Tags: objective-c

I want to set shadow to parent view. But I want child views to remain the same.

What I do now is

```
parentView.layer.shadowRadius = 0.8;
parentView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;
parentView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.4);
```

However, if I do this, the child views are also changed. Is there a way to set the shadow but keep the child views the same.

Thank you

Comment: you try use `layer.masksToBounds = YES;` for child view.

Comment: @bluesky AFAIK this won't do anything.

Answer (score 14):

Is your parentView by any chance transparent? I've set up a simple project and used your code. I've changed some values to see a shadow a little better. This is how it looks:

[image]

As you can see - no shadow on the subview. parentView's background color is set to white. When I set it to clear color this is what happens. I added the border to prove that parentView is still there:

[image]

Apple [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/LayerStyleProperties/LayerStyleProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH10-SW18) prove this:

> Figure A-7 shows several different versions of the same sample layer
>   with a red shadow applied. The left and middle versions include a
>   background color so the shadow appears only around the border of the
>   layer. However, the version on the right does not include a background
>   color. In this case, the shadow is applied to the layer’s content,
>   border, and sublayers.

[image]